# Entity framework DbContext in wcf per call instance mode

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, structuremap, repository-pattern

I have a repository like this

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public TEntity GetByKey(object keyValue)
    {
        // todo
    }
}
```

and a concrete repository like this

```
public CustomerRepository : BaseRepository<Customer> , ICustomerRepository
{
     public CustomerRepository(DbContext context) : base (context) { }

     public Customer FindCustomerByKey(string key)
     {
          _dbContext.Set<Customer>().Find(key);
     }

}
```

I have wcf service like this

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class CustomerSatisfactionService : ICustomerSatisfactionService
{
    private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    private IHelpDeskRepository _helpdeskRepository;


    public AccountService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository,IHelpdeskRepository  helpdeskRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _helpdeskRepository = helpdeskRepository;
    }

    public void DoSomethingUsingBothRepositories()
    {
         //   start unit of work
         // _customerRepository.DoSomething();
         // _helpdeskRepository.DoSomething();
         // commit unit of work
    }


 }
```

and I am using [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/) for injecting DbContext instances like this

```
For<DbContext>().Use(() => new MyApplicationContext());
```

My problem is when a client calls the service, a new  `CustomerSatisfactionService` instance is created, hence new instances of `CustomerRepository` and `HelpdeskRepository` are created but with different DbContexts.

I want to implement the unit of work pattern, but in the `DoSomethingWithBothRepositories` method, the two repositories have different DbContexts.

Is there any way to tell structure map to spin up a DbContext instance on a per call basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify lifecycle for your DbContext so that only one instance is created per call. StructureMap doesn't contain build-in lifecycle management for per call WCF but you can find one implementation on [this blog](http://blog.mikeobrien.net/2010/01/creating-structuremap-lifecycle-for-wcf.html).

Comment: hi Ladislav...seems this can be a solution...will try and let you know...thanks.

Comment: i found the exact answer here http://andreasohlund.net/2009/04/27/unitofwork-in-wcf-using-structuremap/

Comment: Your link to the blog is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement UnitOfWork pattern so that same context is shared amongst entities. Take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx for a way to implement it.

Comment: DbContext already is unit of work implementation so this does not solve the problem of lifetime management in with IoC like structure map.

Comment: It is if the same context was used by all repositories. Since the context is enclosed within the repositories, to make it work, some solution to manage the context is needed. Unit of work is one such way. Another way could be to use context factory that creates and returns same context. IMHO, the underlined issue here is not the lifetime of the context but each repository getting a different context within the same call. Once that is solved using any pattern, any DI can be used to create the context.

Comment: Lifecycle management exactly solves this if you want to inject context into repository and repository into service. And it solves it without any internal dependency on UoWFactory. But it is just architecture decission.

Comment: @amit..in that post..the DbContext is given to the repository through constructor..but i want to give it through dependencyInjection (i.e thru structureMap)...structureMap creates new instances for every repository..but i want it to create new instance per wcf request...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need/want StructureMap to control the instantiation of dbcontext, have a look at this reply, UoW and UoW Factory setup dbcontext for the calls that need to be made in the repository.

[EF ObjectContext, Service and Repository - Managing context lifetime.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169188/ef-objectcontext-service-and-repositry-managing-context-lifetime/1170308#1170308)

Comment: Hi Jtew...that question does not answer my query..i want two repositories to use same context...it can be done if i dont use DI, but i want to do that with DI